# Why is my regular expression skipping the dot instead of matching the string before it?

Tags: ruby, regex, irb

I was trying to work out a regular expression in IRB and got some unexpected output.
The goal was to match everything up until the last dot in a FQDN.

So, for example, if I was trying to match the string `"flowtechconsulting.com"`,
I started with the following:

```
s1.sub(/^(.*)\\./, "\\1")   #=> "flowtechconsultingcom"
```

However, the `sub` function simply returned everything but the dot, instead of the first matching group.

If I add two matching groups it works:

```
s1.sub(/^(.*)\\.(.*)$/, "\\1")   #=> "flowtechconsulting"
```

I'm just not sure why the first doesn't work. It seems like it should.

Comment: @iAmRubuuu Your edit is unacceptable. It's good that you formatted it, but it is bad that you changed the ruby expressions. Even if they are wrong, you need to keep that. Otherwise, the result that the OP got and the question can change.

Comment: +1 @sawa, the edit is inadequate because it doesn't fix grammar and spelling errors. The source changes were due to the change in formatting, but grammar and spelling changes were not sufficient.

Comment: `sub` is not for matching patterns, it's for replacing text that matches the pattern. Use [`Regexp.match`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html#method-i-match) or see Ruby's [`String.regex`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/^(.*)\./` only captures everything up to the dot.  The "com" is not captured and thus not replaced in the substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about `sub`, and do something like:

```
"foo.bar.baz.com"[/(.*)(?:\.)/, 1]
# => "foo.bar.baz"
```